# adjusting treasury futures exposure using micros

Tags: volatility, portfolio-management, futures, bond-yields

I want to decrease my exposure to a 10-year note futures by using 10-year micro futures after volatility-adjusting them. I've calculated that the difference in volatility in the micro has  5.125x the volatility of a full-sized.

How many micros would I need to have the same exposure as a full-sized contract after volatility-adjusting them?

Comment: Hmm... the Micro Yield Futures (10Y) have a margin requirement one eight ($\frac{1}{8}$) the size of the Ten Year Futures (ZN) margin requirement. They cannot be 5.125 times *more* volatile. The CME takes volatility into account in setting margin requirements. (Do you mean the Micros have approximately one fifth the volatility?).

Comment: I think this is due to the contract size. The full sized has a larger multiplier and lower vol, but higher notional compared to the micro. The micro only has a 1000x multiplier. I think my volatility calculation for the micros is wrong, however. I think the micros gave around 44% vol